# fixed point theory: need help with this proposition $\|x-T(x)\| \leq \|x-P_{Fix(T)}(x)\| $

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

can someone help me with this problem:

Let T:$ \ \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ a non linear mapping.
We say T is $\gamma$-strongly quasi-nonexpansive with $\gamma \geq0$ if:
$\|T(x)-z\|^2 \leq \|x-z\|^2-\gamma\|T(x)-x\|^2   , \ \forall x \in\mathbb{R}^n,z\in Fix(T)  $

Another equal definition is that $\frac{1+\gamma}{2}*\|x-T(x)\|^2 \leq\langle x-T(x),x-z\rangle$, for $z \in Fix(T)$ and $\forall x \in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Proof: Let T be a $\gamma$-strongly quasi-nonexpansive mapping with $ \gamma \geq1.$ Then,

$\|x-T(x)\| \leq \|x-P_{Fix(T)}(x)\| $,

where $P_{Fix(T)}(x)$ represents the projection onto the fixed-point set of T.

Comment: Something doesn't look right here.  $\gamma\geq 1$ does nothing since we can always increase $\gamma$ without spoiling the condition.

Comment: ahh yes. sorry. it's supposed to be a minus gamma in the first definition. i now corrected it.

Comment: Then by definition, $\gamma\lVert T(x)-x\rVert^2\leq\lVert x-z\rVert^2$ for all $x,z$, which immediately gives you the result since $\gamma>1$ and you can take $z=P_{\operatorname{Fix}T}x\in\operatorname{Fix}T$.

Comment: Well. that makes damn sense. thank you !